# Parse multiple page PDF to multiple bitmaps on andorid

Tags: android

I want to get a PDF file (witch contains multiple pages) from my device using Intent and then parse this pdf to multiple images and show them in my ViewPager. I successfully got file from my device, but how to parse pdf to multiple bitmaps on android?

Answer (score 1):

## Tool to parse: `Android-ImageMagick`

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) to parse PDF files.

There is an android port: [paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick: Android port for ImageMagick](https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick) based on [techblue/jmagick](https://github.com/techblue/jmagick) Java library.

## Command to parse:

Try something like this:

```sh
convert           \
   -verbose       \
   -density 150   \
   -trim          \
    <your-PDF-file>.pdf      \
   -quality 100   \
   -flatten       \
   -sharpen 0x1.0 \
    <1-100 page numbers>.jpg
```

P.S.: `convert` is a part of `ImageMagick` package

Comment: Can you, please, provide a quick example how I can do this with this library?

Comment: Please check `USAGE` section of [the repo](https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick). There is comprehensive guide